# How to implement view-based spring security for links?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a new project and I want to implement `spring-security` along with other components of `spring framekwork`.

I plan to implement spring security into 2 levels, **Request URL-level** and **view-level**

- For **Request URL-Level**, I'd use the `<intercept-url>` tag to restrict URL access only for authorized users.
- For **View-Level** security, I'll use it into two parts of the application;

  - For the web app **menu** to restrict menus for users who authorized to.
  - And **inside the pages** to restrict some parts of the page for users who authorized to.

---

The confusion I had is regarding implement spring security for **menu** links.
Hence I need to use spring `taglibs` `<authorize>` tag's `url` attribute (to reuse`<intercept-url>` patterns/access combination) , then I'll need to write menu links by hand like this:

```
<security:authorize url="/admin/superadmin/**" >
        <a href="superadmin/index.jsp">Super admin page</a>
</security:authorize>
```

Where I've the following intercept url rule:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/superadmin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')" />
```

The point is, I have all the rules in the Database table, and I want to draw links dynamically based on the roles/links saved in the table.

So, ***the question is*** how to draw menu links dynamically, and at the same time still use the `<authorize>` taglib?

Comment: If you draw the menu dynamically, would it be an option to only draw accessible items ? Say differently, do you have access to current logged in user when you draw the menu ?

Comment: Yes, of course I've access to the users and his permissions (roles), but this case I'll generate the code of the authorize tag.. or I'll not use it at all. Correct?

Comment: Can you give more clarifications please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<authorize>` tag can do what you need automatically. I assume your menu JSP looks like (without the security part) :

```
<c:foreach items="${menus}" var="menu">
    <a href=${menu.url}>${menu.label}</a>
</c:foreach>
```

You can simply add security that way :

```
<c:foreach items="${menus}" var="menu">
    <security:authorize url=${menu.url}>
        <a href=${menu.url}>${menu.label}</a>
    </security:authorize>
</c:foreach>
```

The Spring security reference manual says that as you use the namespace the `authorize` tags *creates a dummy web request for the supplied URL and invokes the security interceptor to see whether the request would succeed or fail. This allows you to delegate to the access-control setup you defined using intercept-url declarations within the  namespace configuration and saves having to duplicate the information (such as the required roles) within your JSPs*